# iPhone cannot reach local server by IP address, unless server first pings iPhone

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iphone

My desktop development machine is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running apache2 as a web server. My iPhone is an iPhone 12 Pro running iOS Version 17.3.1. UFW is disabled on the Ubuntu machine. I have only one network at my home which is powered by a Ubiquiti gateway appliance.

Occassionally, I need to access my web development server by its IP Address via web browser on my iPhone.

Historically, this has never been a problem. However as of late (I can't say exactly when...), my iPhone has been been unable to reach this server at all. Both HTTP/HTTPS requests via web browser ultimately time out, and the phone is unable to ping the server using a network tools app I have installed called "iNetTools"

Other machines on this network (e.g., my laptop) can reach the Ubuntu web server without issue, and can ping the Ubuntu machine as well. Similarly, the Ubuntu machine can ping the iPhone. I've confirmed via Unifi software that both the iPhone and Ubuntu server are on the same 5ghz channel and even on the same AP (mesh network), just to eliminate those nuances as potential variables.

I discovered that, after pinging the iPhone from the Ubuntu machine, suddenly the HTTP/HTTPS requests from the iPhone begin working, and the iPhone is then also able to ping the Ubuntu machine. This "sticks" for some time until eventually it stops working (iPhone can once again no longer reach Ubuntu server) and like clockwork, pinging the iPhone from the Ubuntu server restores functionality.

I feel like this suggests some sort of privacy setting on my iPhone (perhaps due a recent iOS update??) as like I mentioned, other devices are able to communicate with this server (and each other) consistently without problem.

I see both devices (the Ubuntu server and iPhone) listed in the Ubiquiti/Unifi client list. I'm never able to ping the Ubuntu server from the iPhone unless the Ubuntu server first initiates a ping to the iPhone. This ping always takes a few seconds before it succeeds; the first response typically comes around ~3000ms, then ~2000ms then ~1000ms after which response times are what you'd expect, < 10ms.

Comment: This is perhaps a firewall problem. Turn off temporarily the firewalls on both sides and try again.

Comment: A firewall issue seems far more likely, but depending on the router setup, is _Private Wi-Fi Address_ enabled on the iPhone for the Ubiquiti's wifi? If so, does disabling that and reconnecting to the wifi result in the same issue? _(Randomized MACs on a trusted LAN wifi can create issues depending on the subnet mask used for the network the wifi on the router and the configuration of the DHCP server (e.g. how many IPs are available for DHCP) - for example, I heavily restrict DHCP IPs on my home network since I exclusively use static IPs)_

Comment: This feels like a buggy Wi-Fi implementation is breaking group keying, thus breaking multicasts and broadcasts, thus breaking ARP. Make sure you don't have original WPA (TKIP) allowed as an option on your APs. You want WPA2-only (AES-CCMP only) or better. Many Wi-Fi implementations have had bugs around handling original WPA (TKIP) as the group cipher when using WPA2 (AES-CCMP) as the unicast cipher. It's best to keep original WPA completely disabled.

Comment: @harrymc I agree that it presents like a firewall problem, however there is no firewall enabled on the Ubuntu server. I'm unaware of any user-controlled firewall on iPhones.

Comment: @JW0914 private WiFi is disabled on the iPhone. I can test using a static IP on the iPhone; the Ubuntu server does have a static IP.

Comment: @Spiff I've tested two different routers (from different manufacturers) and have the same behavior which I feel rules out the WiFi implementation. Only WPA2 is present on the Ubiquiti appliance, PMF is disabled, SSID is set to broadcast, and various security features such as Client Device Isolation are all disabled on Ubiquiti appliance.